# Cassandra : javax.persistence.PersistenceException: InvalidRequestException(why:Undefined name)

Tags: cassandra, kundera

I don't have `kundera.ddl.auto.prepare" value="update"` in my persistence.xml file; however, when I try to persisting an entity into Cassandra using Kundera API I get the following exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException:<b> InvalidRequestException(why:Undefined name affiliateTypeCodeAndBusinessAffiliateAccountNumber in where clause </B>('affiliateTypeCodeAndBusinessAffiliateAccountNumber EQ 'W177043432821''))
    at com.impetus.client.cassandra.CassandraClientBase.executeCQLQuery(CassandraClientBase.java:1925) [kundera-cassandra-2.9.1-ATT-1.jar:na]
    at com.impetus.client.cassandra.CassandraClientBase$CQLClient.executeQuery(CassandraClientBase.java:2101) [kundera-cassandra-2.9.1-ATT-1.jar:na]
    at com.impetus.client.cassandra.CassandraClientBase.executeSelectQuery(CassandraClientBase.java:833) [kundera-cassandra-2.9.1-ATT-1.jar:na]
```

Why am I getting this exception, and how I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please share few more details. Prima facie it looks to me CQL3 case senstivity issue

-Vivek